# Layout without any margins on QGIS

Tags: qgis, layouts

I have a world map that I want to export without any margins. I add it to a layout but it has a different shape than the default layout, producing some white space at the edges as shown in the picture.

[image]

How can I get rid of it, and instead get a layout without any margins?

Answer (score 8):

Go to the <kbd>Layout</kbd> tab and expand the entry <kbd>Resize Layout to Content</kbd>, then click on <kbd>Resize Layout</kbd>.

[image]

The layout size then adapts to extent of the items you have placed on the layout. So be sure to first adapt the frame of the the map (black line in the next screenshot) to the size you want the layout to have. When you change the frame around the map, the scale adapts. To avoid this, set a fixed scale, using data driven override (red arrow) and enter a number - e.g. `150.000.000` as in my example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I imagined there had to be an option like that, but nothing changes when I click on it.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Looks like my item has white space. If I scale it down and follow these steps, the layout adapts to the item, but the white space inside of it remains.

Comment: Set afixed scale - use data driven override and insert a number for the scale. Then you can change the frame and the scale does not change

Comment: I do not know how to do that with that information.

Comment: See 2nd screenshot, red arrow: click on the `ɛ` icon and in the opening dialog, simply introduce a numer for the scale you want to have and cofirm with OK. Does that help? If not: where are you stuck?