# Layout Manager and Map Size

Tags: qgis, layouts, scale

I am trying to create two really simple maps with the QGIS Layout Manager. I can adjust the size of the map with scale and the extents - but why is there that blank white space around, and why is the blank space different for my two maps, even if the maps are the same and just some layers are different.

How do I create two maps which are the same size and have the same sized symbols and legend items/text?

[image]

Comment: See here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/445296/88814

Comment: Hey, it didn't work as expected. I edited my post and included a picture to show what it looks like when I follow the instructions you provided. I believe the issue may be that the white space is actually just an inverted white polygon.

Comment: If you instead looked at the Page Layout Item Properties tab (you are showing the Layout tab) you would see where you can select/change page size.  If you click in your map itself and go to the Map Item properties you can change the size of your map to better fit the page size you want.  If you want two maps on one page use the Add Map button to draw them and then fine tune size/location in each map item properties.  If you want to duplicate a layout to make two pages then in the Layout select duplicate layout menu item.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I need two separate maps with the same basemap. However, when I copy the page width from one layout manager to the other, the map sizes are completely different. Both maps use the same CRS and the exact same extent for my area of interest. And there is still this white space around.

Comment: Under the Item Properties, what are the Position and Size properties for both maps? Are these identical?